# C++ Checking for Date and Time

Tags: c++

I'm developing a test code and one of the requirements is to check if the text contains the date and time in the following format.

DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM

I am completely lost about how to do this

Can someone point me in the right direction?

My only thought was to analyse every character in the string one by one but that seems very long winded, there must be a short way?

```
if (pos != string::npos)
            {
            mystring=mystring.erase (0,13);
                           {      
                             int z=0;

                             if (isalpha(mystring[0])) z+1;
                             cout << z << endl;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[1])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[3])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[4])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[6])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[7])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[8])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[9])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[11])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[12])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[14])) z+1;
                             if (isalpha(mystring[15])) z+1;

                             if (mystring[0] > 3)  z+1;
                             cout << z << endl;  
                             if (mystring[3] > 1)  z+1;  
                             if (mystring[6] != 2)  z+1;    
                             if (mystring[7] != 0) z+1;      
                             if (mystring[8] != 1)  z+1;       
                             if (mystring[9] != 4)  z+1;
                             if (mystring[11] > 2)  z+1;
                             if (mystring[14] > 6)  z+1;


                           cout << mystring << "\n" << z << endl;

                                if (z != 0 ) {cout << "Please enter a valid Date & Time" << endl;}


                           }
            }
```

why is this wrong? :(

Comment: Are you trying to do this at a low level or use niceties?

Comment: Either will do,
This is my second day of coding, sorry but whats regex?

Comment: You don't yet understand what you're doing well enough to ask a specific question. This site is for specific questions. You just need to learn C++.

Comment: There are lots of stuff. strftime, regex, also sscanf can do this.

Comment: Well then, you want low level. That means you should look at the problem with a pen/cil & paper. Imagine there's no computer available and you were asked to do this manually. That process can be directly translated with code. Is `DD` an `int` within the bounds of `days`? Is there a `/` where appropriate? Turn that into code; if specific questions arise in the process, check back. If no question exists that answers your question, ask your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C you can use **sscanf**, here is an example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   const char* buffer = "05/11/1996 13:24";

   int day, month, year;
   int hour, minute;
   if(sscanf(buffer, "%2d/%2d/%4d %d:%d",
      &month,
      &day,
      &year,
      &hour,
      &minute) == 5)
   {
      printf("parsed: DAY %d MONTH %d YEAR %d HOUR %d MINUTE %d\n",  day, month, year, hour, minute);

      // do further validations 
   }
   else
   {    
     printf("parse error, string do not contain valid date-time\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: I've adapted this to be used with my string, however the &minute) == 5) is giving an error for some reason